# Click on coordinates using WinAppDriver

Tags: c#, appium, winappdriver

I have a windows application and I have to test it on a remote machine using WinAppDriver and Appium.

during the test I need to click on a specific point of the screen.
I have tried several ways but it doesn't work .

Is there anyway so I can do this?!

Answer (score 0):

Try next [code](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/810#issuecomment-592151951) using IWebElement extension. It is working locally.

```cs
public static IWebElement ClickByPoints(this IWebElement element, Point point)
{
    new Actions(((IWrapsDriver)element).WrappedDriver).MoveToElement(element, 0, 0).MoveByOffset(point.X, point.Y).Click()
        .Perform();
}
```